# Show number of pages next to Flickr threads

Tags: javascript, userscript

This is a userscript that simply adds the number of pages that a thread has next to its title for [Flickr interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBzTK.png). (FWIW it's not really done because the script is only loaded at page load, but not reloaded on subsequent AJAX calls that the user may make).

I'm far from being a seasoned JS developer, so I'm looking for guidelines to potentially bring the script to state-of-the-art JS standards.

Example of questions that I'm not sure about:

- Should I use promises?
- Is the workflow done well?
- Is the inline CSS/HTML evil in this case?
- Should I omit jQuery?
- Am I making too many jQuery calls? (i.e. should I just make one query and find the next rows through `siblings` or something similar?)

Any pointers are appreciated! (this is also my first userscript, so feedback about the userscript itself is also appreciated)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Flickr - Number of pages in a thread
// @namespace   flickr_
// @description This user script is simply displaying the number of pages in a thread on the main page of the group
// @include     http*://*flickr.com/groups/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js
// ==/UserScript==


var api_key = 'fe753c0dd6068fb6c74cb70458b1b9a0';
var POSTS_PER_PAGE = 100;


function call_flickr(method, params, callback) {
    'use strict';
    var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?";
    params.api_key = api_key;
    params.format = 'json';
    params.nojsoncallback = 1;
    params.method = method;
    $.get(url, params, function (data) {
        callback(JSON.parse(data));
    });
}


function number_of_pages(data) {
    'use strict';
    var url = '/groups/' + data.topics.path_alias + '/discuss/';
    data.topics.topic.forEach(function (topic) {
        var pages_number = Math.ceil(topic.count_replies / POSTS_PER_PAGE);
        var link = url + topic.id + '/';
        var last_link = link + 'page' + pages_number;
        var current_element = $('a[href=' + link + ']');
        if (pages_number > 1) {
            current_element.after(' <a style="font-size:12px; color:#aaa;" href="' +
                    last_link + '">' + pages_number + '</a>');
        }
    });
}


function threads_list(data) {
    'use strict';
    var group_id = data.group.id;
    var params = {};
    params.group_id = group_id;
    call_flickr('flickr.groups.discuss.topics.getList', params, number_of_pages);
}


function main() {
    'use strict';
    var params = {};
    params.url = document.URL;
    call_flickr('flickr.urls.lookupGroup', params, threads_list);
}


main();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all I not so used to `usercript`. But in general I think your solution is overengineered.

**I can point:**

- Readability of code is not good.
- The "standar" for JavaScript usually is camel case.

**Regarding your questions:**

1. You don't have any complicated workflow or expecting several answers, so I wouldn't use promises.
2. As I said before, I think your code is really hard to read for only being three functions
3. You could remove the HTML in line creating the elements by JavaScript, but I don't think is so much for calling it "evil"...
4. You could
5. Don't think so

**Few changes I would made:**

Only declare one, `'use strict'`

```
var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?";

var POSTS_PER_PAGE = 100;

var params = {
    url: document.URL,
    api_key: 'fe753c0dd6068fb6c74cb70458b1b9a0',
    method: 'flickr.urls.lookupGroup',
    format: 'json',
    nojsoncallback: 1
};
```

Whit this change I don't think that you are gaining so much whit your current function `call_flickr`.

So I would split it in two functions each one whit the call. Like this:

```
'use strict';

var url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?";

var POSTS_PER_PAGE = 100;

var params = {
    url: document.URL,
    api_key: 'fe753c0dd6068fb6c74cb70458b1b9a0',
    format: 'json',
    nojsoncallback: 1
};


function numberOfPages(data) {
    var url = '/groups/' + data.topics.path_alias + '/discuss/';
    data.topics.topic.forEach(function (topic) {
        var pages_number = Math.ceil(topic.count_replies / POSTS_PER_PAGE);
        var link = url + topic.id + '/';
        var last_link = link + 'page' + pages_number;
        var current_element = $('a[href=' + link + ']');
        if (pages_number > 1) {
            current_element.after(' <a style="font-size:12px; color:#aaa;" href="' +
                    last_link + '">' + pages_number + '</a>');
        }
    });
}


function threadsList(data) {
    params.group_id = data.group.id;
    params.method = 'flickr.groups.discuss.topics.getList';

    $.get(url, params, function (data) {
        numberOfPages(JSON.parse(data));
    });
}


function main() {

    params.method = 'flickr.urls.lookupGroup';

    $.get(url, params, function (data) {
        threadsList(JSON.parse(data));
    });

}


main();
```